# Open or create a specific Vimwiki page from a command prompt

Tags: bash, invocation, plugin-vimwiki

For opening the index page of my Vimwiki instance, I have the following alias in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias vimwiki='vim -c VimwikiIndex'
```

But how to open a specific Vimwiki page right from a command prompt?

Answer (score 2):

Add a function like this to you `~/.bashrc`:

```
function vimwikipage() {
  vim -c "VimwikiIndex" -c "VimwikiGoto $1"
}
```

Now, you can open/create a specific Vimwiki page like this:

```
$ vimwikipage ExampleVimwikiPage
```

## Explanation

This command would be essentially equivalent to the following sequence of actions:

```
$ vim
\ww
:VimwikiGoto ExampleVimwikiPage
```

(I assume that `VimwikiIndex` is mapped to `\ww`, which is a default Vimwiki mapping.)